# Issue with cin's and cout's in functions

Tags: c++

I'm having and issue with my menu driven program that is calling functions.The compiler tells me that all of my cin's,cout's, and my endl statements inside my functions are errors when i try to execute the program. Any advice on how to fix this?

edit

The error its giving me states that the cout's, cin's, and endl's are all undeclared identifiers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;


    double ic(double inches, double centimeters)
    {
        cout << "Enter inches" << endl;
        cin >> inches;
        centimeters = 2.54*inches;
        return centimeters;
    }

    double ci(double centimeters, double inches)
    {
        cout << "Enter centimeters" << endl;
        cin >> centimeters;
        inches = centimeters * .3937007874;
        return inches;
    }

    double fim(int feet, double inches, double meters)
    {
        cout << "Enter feet " << endl;
        cin >> feet;
        cout << "Enter inches " << endl;
        cin >> inches;
        inches = feet * 12 + inches;
        meters = inches / 39.370;
        return meters;
    }

    double mfi(double meters, int feet, double inches)
    {
        feet = 0;
        inches = 0;
        meters = 0;
        cout << "Enter meters. " << endl;
        cin >> meters;
        inches = meters * 39.37;
        while (inches > 12)
        {
            if (inches > 12)
                inches = inches - 12;
            feet++;
        }
        return feet, inches;
    }



int main()
{
    double inches, meters, centimeters;
    int exit = 1, feet;
    char choice;

    while (exit == 1)
    {
        cout << "Basic Conversion Calculator" << endl
            << "a. Inches to centimeters" << endl
            << "b. Centimeters to inches" << endl
            << "c. Feet and inches to meters" << endl
            << "d. Meters to feet and inches" << endl
            << "e. Quit" << endl;


        cout << "Insert Option:";
        cin >> choice;



        switch (choice)
        {
        case 'a':  case 'A':
            centimeters = ic(inches, centimeters);
            cout << centimeters << "cm" << endl;
            break;

        case 'b': case 'B':
            inches = ci(centimeters, inches);
            cout << inches << "in" << endl;
            break;

        case 'c': case 'C':
            meters = fim(feet, inches, meters);
            cout << meters << "m" << endl << endl;
            break;

        case 'd': case 'D':
            feet = mfi(meters, feet, inches);
            inches = mfi(meters, feet, inches);
            cout << feet << " ft and " << inches << "in" << endl;
            break;

        case 'e': case 'E':

            exit = 0;
            break;

        default:
            cout << "Input Error!" << endl;

        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which errors in particular? Put the error messages verbatim in your question please.

Comment: Not sure what you intended `return feet, inches;` to do, but I'd guess it's not doing what you wanted (it's equivalent to `return inches;`).

Comment: I'm very new to using functions, can i not return 2 values that way? This is an assignment for my programming class. and everything has to be in a function for this assignment. With that said how would i return 2 values from 1 function?

Comment: No, a function can only return one value. If you want to return multiple values, either return a structure, or use reference arguments so the function can modify the caller's variable.

Comment: Why does the function that returns meters also take a `meter` argument that it never uses?

Comment: And instead of a `while` loop that subtracts 12, use `fmod()` to calculate the modulus.

Comment: The error message you're getting is what would happen if you didn't have `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;`. Since you show those in the question, I can only assume that the real program is different from what you posted.

Comment: Thats the exact program as is. Thats why im confused. There should be no errors pertaining to the couts/ins/endl statements. As for my other errors im working on fixing myself. I just wanted some other people to look and see if they could tell where that error was coming from.

Answer (score -1):

I copied your code into my visual studio, and it's working perfectly! :)

It does have another problem which I fixed by me in order to make it work:
The variables "double inches, meters, centimeters; int feet;" are used in the switch before you gave them any value. You can just make them all a 0, because you are anyways getting new values from the user in the function.

Hope I was helpful!
Good luck!

Comment: Okay thats good to know, dont know why im having issues in my VS...maybe its just a weird bug. thank you for the help.